# How to fix ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I'm getting below error while executing PS script

`Error Code: ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
More Information: The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom is installed.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.`

For this Fix I followed [POST](https://forums.iis.net/t/1235672.aspx?Web%20Deploy%20ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER) and did whatever suggested but no luck. Any idea?

You can find more detail on this issue on [This Post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18767/getting-issue-while-setting-up-sitecore-habitat-9-0-update-2/18773?noredirect=1#comment29067_18773)

Comment: Have you tried using the script dom assembly from the [latest NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/)?

Comment: I installed `DACFramework.msi` so assuming this installed required dlls. Don't know where to execute `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64 -Version 150.4384.2` command.

Apart from that I found `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies` folder and moved dll successfully to GAC as per post but still getting same error